# subclipse: Unable to load default SVN Client

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am constantly getting this error when working with eclispe and the subclipse plugin:

```
Unable to load default SVN Client
```

I have already installed both the SVNKit and the JavaHL provider, but it can't be found in the preferences:

[image]

I am using eclipse for win64bit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What JavaHL provider have you installed? It sounds like you need 64 bit JavaHL support. Have you tried SlikSVN?

Comment: was this the solution? Use SilkSVN?

Answer (score 78):

I had this problem after installing the latest eclipse and installing subclipse from the marketplace. To resolve you can follow these steps:

1. Click **Help** >> **Install New Software...**
2. Set **Work with**: `Subclipse 1.10.x Update Site - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x`
3. Ensure **Hide items that are already installed** is checked.
4. Click **Select All**.
5. Click **Next**.
6. Complete the remainder of the installation as usual.

Comment: This really solved the problem. First I installed Subversion 1.8 and Eclipse was throwing 'Enable to load default SVN client'. Than I removed version 1.8, and installed all from 1.6 repository. Worked out.

Comment: Strange but somehow downgrading the version to 1.6 worked for me too

Comment: In reference to the "why does downgrading work?", have any of you considered checking which version of subversion your server is using? Chances are, it's running 1.6.x!

From the tigris website itself: "Subclipse 1.6.x includes and requires **Subversion 1.6.x client** features and working copy format."

Comment: For me the problem persisted after this as well, so I went to:

1. Windows->Preferences->Team->Svn

2. Change client to SvnKit(Pure Java)

Courtesy: http://kunjans.wordpress.com/2013/07/12/subclipse-unable-to-load-default-svn-client/

Comment: This solved the problem for me. I had the same issue with Eclipse Oxygen and CollabNet Edge and Subclipse 1.8.x. But 1.10.x solved the issue.

Comment: In the year 2019 in eclipse 4.10 I add this URL to `Available Software Sites` to get subclipse: https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/

Answer (score 28):

For ubuntu 12.04 amd64

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
```

add this to eclipse.ini after -vmargs:

```
-vmargs
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
...
```

Comment: This only works if you are running Subversion 1.7 or later.  The default version subversion in the 12.04 repo is 1.6.5.  Do a `svn --version` if you are not sure. Here is the bug report and the workaround:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/949143

Comment: This solution works for older versions of Eclipse when your svn client is 1.8+.

Comment: You saved my day.  Also works with Ubuntu 14.04 amd64.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this with easiest way:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java

sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/* /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same problem after installed subclipse 1.8 from eclipse marketplace and resolved thru following steps:
1. Install subversion client (required)
2. Install Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter (required)

And it works now.

P/S: Eclipse Indigo

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about *JavaHL* but to make the *SVNKit* appear on the list of SVN interfaces, you need to install the "*SVN Client Adapter*" and the "*SVNKit Adapter*" as well.

You can find those on the update site of Subclipse (*http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x*).

Comment: Installing "SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required)" from Eclipse Marketplace solved the issue for me! Funny thing that "Not required" is part of the plugin-name, but obviously *is* required.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with Subclipse 1.8. Due to licenses limitations, SVN client aren't bundled with SVN any more. So I find the message "Unable to load default SVN Client".

My solutions is to install SVN client. It can't be easier. Go to Eclispe Marketplace, type Subclipse and click to install Subclipse again, select all options. When restarting Eclipse, it will prompt us to install an SVN client, choose SVNKit or JavaHL (I choose JavaHL). After restarting one more time, it all works.

Comment: Your approach helped me after updating Ubuntu Linux from 13.10 to 14.04. The Upgrade probably updated the native svn client. After installing Subclipse from the Eclipse Marketplace as described above, it is likely that the internal format of the working copy, or rather many copies (one for each Eclipse project), have changed and need to be upgraded from within Eclipse. Select Project Folder, Right Mouse Click, Team..., Upgrade... A dialog box appears. Click yes.

Answer (score 1):

In fedora 16 on x64 i meet also, i solved by downloading subversion 1.7 from [here](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=276745) and installing:

```
yum install subversion-javahl-1.7.1-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm  subversion-libs-1.7.1-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm subversion-1.7.1-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Install SVN on Eclipse Juno using the update site at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Go to Help -> Install new software, then Add update site.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Studio 9 if you upgrade/update to 9.0.3 you will get this error as well. You need to uninstall all subEclipse and JavaHL stuff then follow the install procedures again and restart Zend studio.

Build 20120625 in Zend Version 9.0.3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Subversive plugin (which is newer than the Subclipse one, and the two are easily confused with one another), you might run into problems finding the library even after configuring the library path in eclipse.ini. To fix the entire problem, you might need to add this setting to the file as well:

```
-Dsubversion.native.library=C:/SlikSVN_JavaHL/libsvnjavahl-1.dll
```

Read http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php for more help, it's a good-quality explanation of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Spring STS 3.5.1 and Sub eclipse version 1.6. Upgraded to version 1.10 of subeclipse and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The above problem arises with custom eclipse installation and due to updated version of subclipse.

You have to install the older version of subclipse manually.

For this i have done as following:

Under Help menu click "Install New Software..."
Select "http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x" from the drop down menu
If URL of any other advanced version of are available change it to look as above.

Check the options selected are sensible e.g. "Hide items that are already installed"
Click "Select All"
Click Next/Finish through to completion.

After finishing the installation,under windows menu go to preferences,click on Team and on SVN.
Now change the client from Java HL to SVN pure kit.

That's it.

This resolved problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

I solved this problem as follows

1) Install Subversive - SVN Team Provider 4.0.5 from [marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider)

2) **Team -> SVN -> SVN Connectors** and set **SVNKit 1.8.14**

3) Restart eclipse

All works well