# Installed Subclipse for Eclipse - How do I check if it installed successfully?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I installed Subclipse for Eclipse. How do I check if it is working properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to looking at the installed plugins, I would also recommend just going to the Preferences.  If the plugin is installed, there should be an entry under Team > SVN.  You should also see JavaHL and/or SVNKit on the preference page in the list of available client adapters.  You must have one of those successfully installed for Subclipse to work.  They are both on the same update site as Subclipse.

Comment: Yes, i see it under- SVN > SVN Interface: Client: <seen here>

Comment: If you see the preferences, and there is a client adapter installed, then that should answer your question.  It means Subclipse is installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of your istalled plugins. Here is the reference how to do that: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_plug-ins_have_been_installed%3F

Comment: Okay. I see the plugins listed there. Even if your plugin installed correctly, it may not run - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303293/subclipse-and-javahl-installation-headache

So, is there a way to check if the plugin is also working ?

Comment: Have you tried to make a merge to see if popup with 6 merge options are shown?

Comment: No, I do not know how to use SVN yet. I am installing this plugin so that I can learn SVN basics.

Comment: For the latest Eclipse (Kepler), this has moved to Eclipse > About Eclipse > Installation Details.